# Difference between std::logical_not and std::not1?

Tags: c++, std

Please explain with examples when to use `std::logical_not` and when `std::not1`!

According to documentation, the former is a "unary function object class" while the latter "constructs a unary function object". So at the end of the day both construct a unary function object, don't they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are functors (a class with an `operator()`), but differ slightly on what they negate:

- `std::logical_not<T>::operator()` returns`T::operator!()`. Semantically, it sees `T` as a value and negates it.
- `std::not1<T>::operator()` returns `!(T::operator()(T::argument_type&))`. Semantically, it sees `T` as a predicate and negates it.

`std::not1<T>` is a generalization of `std::logical_not` for more complex use case.

---

> Please explain with examples when to use `std::logical_not` and when `std::not1`

Use `std::logical_not` whenever you can. Use `std::not1` whenever your first option is out. The example on [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not1) gives a case where `std::not1` is necessary:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct LessThan7 : std::unary_function<int, bool>
{
    bool operator()(int i) const { return i < 7; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    std::iota(begin(v), end(v), 0);

    std::cout << std::count_if(begin(v), end(v), std::not1(LessThan7())) << "\n";

    //same as above, but use a lambda function
    std::function<int(int)> less_than_9 = [](int x){ return x < 9; };
    std::cout << std::count_if(begin(v), end(v), std::not1(less_than_9)) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Notice: `unary_function` is deprecated (a lambda is just better).

Comment: The thing is, a lambda has no `argument_type` member, `std::not1` needs it.